# Image reduced by neighborhood in Google Earth Engine appears different in QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, classification, reducers

I have a classified sentinel 2 image. To remove single pixel outliers I have applied ee.Reducer.neighbourHood() which essentially smoothens the image with a mode reducer. Finally when export the image and visualize it in QGIS. It appears different from GEE.

This is how the original image appears
[image: Orignal Image]

This is how the reduced image appears
[image: Reduced]

And this is how exported image appears in QGIS
[image: Exported Image in QGIS]

This is my script

```
var image = ee.Image('projects/ee-muddasir-shah/assets/soilbrightness/reclassify_2605_2019_Median').selfMask();
Map.centerObject(image);
Map.addLayer(image,{min:1, max:3, palette:['yellow','orange','red']},'Image');

var rn = image.reduceNeighborhood({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mode(), 
  kernel:ee.Kernel.square(15),}) 
  
Map.addLayer(rn,{min:1, max:3, palette:['yellow','orange','red']},'Image RN');

//var vis = rn.visualize({min:1, max:3, palette:['yellow','orange','red']});
//Map.addLayer(vis)

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: rn, 
  description:'Image',
  region: image.geometry(),
  scale: 10,
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/38a7a8e9101d990a7e0285ec408d5975

I even tried giving custom visualization and exported that as TIFF however that appears the same